# Javascript: Switch from importing data from XML file to importing data from a JS object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, xml

I need to edit a script to switch from reading XML data from an xml file to reading data from a JS object array instead.

let's assume the xml file is `x.xml`:

```
<xml>
   <location>
     <name>cafe 1</name>
     <address>1 cafe st</address>
   </location>
   <location>
     <name>cafe 2</name>
     <address>2 cafe st</address>
   </location>
</xml>
```

The below code populates an array with data from an xml file

```
$.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               url: "x.xml",
               dataType: "xml",
               success: function(xml) {    
                   $(xml).find('location').each(function(){
   i +=1;
                       var name = $(this).find('name').text();
                       var address = $(this).find('address').text();
                     
                        table[i] = {name:name, address:address};
                       
                               
                   });
```

..can I rewrite that output as

```
var table = [
                  {"name":"cafe 1", "address":"1 cafe st"},
                  {"name":"cafe 2", "address":"2 cafe st"},
                  ]
```

...and call data in the array using

```
var m; 
for ( m = 1; m < table.length-1; m++) {

                      if (table[m].name == "cafe 1" ....
```

Trying to get it working as close to this syntax. I just want to get the values into the array in format shown

```
$(xml).find('location').each(function() {
    i += 1;
    var name = $(this).find('name').text();
    var address = $(this).find('address').text();
    
  table[i] = {name:name, address:address};
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have it, though I simplified your code a bit here

```js
let xml = `<xml>
   <location>
     <name>cafe 1</name>
     <address>1 cafe st</address>
   </location>
   <location>
     <name>cafe 2</name>
     <address>2 cafe st</address>
   </location>
</xml>`

let table = []
$(xml).find('location').each(function(i) {
  // here's one way, using array.push()
  /* 
  table.push({
    name: $(this).find('name').text(),
    address: $(this).find('address').text()
  });
  */
  
  // heres another way, using a specific index
  // i (the index) is supplied by the $.each function
  table[i] = {
    name: $(this).find('name').text(),
    address: $(this).find('address').text()
  }
});

table.forEach(row => {
$('#theTable').append(`<tr><td>${row.name}</td><td>${row.address}</td></tr>`)
})
```

```css
#theTable td {
padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='theTable' border='1'><tr><td>Name</td><td>Address</td></tr></table>
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Is there a way to change `url: "x.xml"` to a different parameter to take raw xml? Much appreciated. I'm trying to change the existing script as little as possible and just change the data source from an xml file to on page xml/array.

Comment: How would you edit the `table.push` section to set each value to an array e.g `table[i] = {name:name, address:address};` I just need to put values into the array from the xml for now thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I dont' follow either of these comments. The first one - you are using ajax to get data from a remote source... are you asking how to just work with data that is already in the page instead of ajax? The second one - table.push() is taking an array `table` and adding indexes to it, so in the case of my answer, `table[1]` is the second index of the table array and has this value:  `{name: 'cafe 2', address: '2 cafe st'}`. Not sure if that helps clear it up...

Comment: Thanks for bearing with me. Yes I am removing ajax from this 3rd party script and I want to work with data on the page. I specifically need to set an incrementer i+=1 to your code so it populates an array like `table[i] = {name:name, address:address};` I updated end of question

Comment: Ok, well my example uses data on the page rather than the ajax - what needs to change there? To your second point, I updated my answer....

Comment: Perfect. That's what I needed. Thank you! :)